# C++ Builder VCL Application Icon not showing

Tags: c++builder, vcl

After upgrading to C++ Builder 10.2 Tokyo, the application icons are no longer showing.

Below is a screenshot showing how the icon is showing on the Application setting page:

[image: Icon is entered on the Applicaiotn page]

However, after compiling and running the application, the icon is not showing:

[image]

It is not showing properly on the Taskbar, either.

In addition, creating a new application and adding the icon does work initially.

But after a few modifications to the application, a few builds, the icon disappears!

My screen is not high resolution, and this issue started with Tokyo edition.

Does anyone know what is going on?